# Create stamina regeneration

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time, operation

I would like my stamina value to regenerate after a few seconds, but only if while the stamina is not used with some function that consumes it (otherwise even while the object runs or performs other actions in the meantime it recharges the stamina)

```
float stamina = 100;
float staminaMax= 100;
float staminaMin= 0;

Update()
stamina = Mathf.Clamp (stamina, staminaMin, staminaMax);

if (stamina<staminaMax) && (maybe condition to indicate time passed since last consumption ??)
stamina = (stamina + (10.0f * Time.DeltaTime));
```

Comment: keep track of state in class fields and use those values to make the decision.

Comment: can you give me a script for the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move using up stamina to seperate method, where you reset timer, and use this timer to determine if you want fillup stamina
something like that:

```
float timer;
void Update(){
    timer -= Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer <= 0f){
        stamina += staminaRefillRate * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

public void UseStamina(float amount){
     stamina -= amount;
     timer = staminaRefreshCooldown;
}
```

It's just a proof of concept it still requires implementing some variables and handling minimal and maximal values
I also strongly recommend you use [unity serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) instead of hardcoding values - it makes easier to change balance and allows you to put objects that use one behaviour but have different numeric configuration